# Phonegap Build: geofence custom plugin issue

Tags: cordova, swift, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I tried to use the [Phonegap Geofence Plugin](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/issues) (written in swift for its iOS part) with my application.
When building the project through Phonegap Build, I get the following [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/QuentinFchx/0fa7e6950bc4e96eef7e) for the iOS build. Files with `.d` extension are not found by XCode during the compilation.

Phonegap Version is the default one in PGBuild: `3.6.3`. I include the plugin through:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.cowbell.cordova.geofence" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```

Is it a plugin or a configuration issue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Swift code can't communicate with the Obj-C code. You need to add a bridge file to fix that.
You need to add a file named `project-Bridging-Header.h` (`project` *need* to be the name of your project, otherwise it won't be detected) along your Swift files.
In it, you'll have to import all dependencies needed for your Swift code to work.

You also have a second issue: sqlite doesn't seem to be included in your build process. Select your project, go to `Build Phases` => `Link Binaries with Libraries` => `+` => type `sqlite` and add the library.
That will make sqlite functions available.